# Protractor: Get text of an alert?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I'm testing my Angular app with Protractor. I've looked through [the docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md) and can't find any way to get the text of an alert. It's not an element in the DOM per se (at least, not that I can figure out; when there's an alert up, Chrome's inspector won't allow you to inspect it). How would I test that an alert has the correct message? Or even, that one is present?

#### Edit

Here is my code. HTML:

```
  <button id='alertButton' data-ng-click='ngAlert()'>Button</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.ngAlert = function(){
  window.alert('Hello');
};
```

Protractor spec:

```
  describe('alert', function(){
    var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    beforeEach(function(){
      button = $('#alertButton');
      button.click();
    });
    it('tells the alert message', function(){
      expect(button.getText()).toEqual('Button');
    });
  });
```

When I make an assertion on the button text like this:

```
it('tells the alert message', function(){
  expect(button.getText()).toEqual('Button');
});
```

It passes. But if I try to read an alert like this:

```
it('tells the alert message', function(){
  var alertDialog = ptor.switchTo().alert();
  expect(alertDialog.getText()).toEqual('Hello');
});
```

I get this error:

> $ protractor spec/e2e/conf.js Using the selenium server at
>   http://localhost:4444/wd/hub .F
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) alert tells the alert message    Message:
>        NoSuchAlertError: no alert open   (Session info: chrome=30.0.1599.101)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=Mac OS
>   X 10.9.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 3 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01'
>   System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version:
>   '10.9', java.version: '1.6.0_65' Session ID:
>   edbaa752eb14ad45f7e961903b69a466 Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{platform=MAC,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.2}, rotatable=false,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, version=30.0.1599.101,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false,
>   takesScreenshot=true}]
>
> Finished in 2.125 seconds 2 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failure
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1542
>         throw error;
>               ^ NoSuchAlertError: no alert open

But I've tested it on the page and it works, and the test can clearly find the button in the DOM. So either the `click()` function isn't working, or something else is going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside your test, get the current Protractor instance and use `switchTo().alert()` to access the `alert` dialog box:

```
var ptor = protractor.getInstance();

var alertDialog = ptor.switchTo().alert();

expect(alertDialog.getText()).toEqual("Hello");
```

Keep in mind that Protractor is basically just a wrapper for Selenium WebDriver so, as far as I know, anything you can do with Selenium WebDriver you can do with Protractor.

Edited to include the full test:

```
describe('Alert dialog', function () {

    var ptor = protractor.getInstance(),
        button;

    beforeEach(function () {
        // This line is necessary on my end to get to my test page.
        // browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8000/test.html');
        button = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('alertButton'));
        button.click();
    });

    it('tells the alert message', function () {
        var alertDialog = ptor.switchTo().alert();
        expect(alertDialog.getText()).toEqual("Hello");
    });

});
```

It is possible that your app is still initializing at the point that your test is executed, which would explain why no dialog seems to be appearing. Ensure that your app is "ready to go" and can actually display the alert before making your assertion. Hope that helps!

Comment: @nickcoxdotme: Clearly there is no alert dialog present when that particular test executes. There must be something else going on. The first test case, as you have above, should throw an `unexpected alert open` in that scenario, since the `beforeEach` should have triggered the dialog. Is this your actual test code, or a simplified case? I've expanded my answer to include the full test, which is working correctly for me. One difference to note is how I'm finding the button element, i.e. the "Protractor way".

Comment: Wow. I've pasted your exact text into my spec file, and it's still saying no alert, even though pressing the button in the browser triggers an alert. (About finding the element, I had also tried your way, but the docs mentioned something I thought was great: "You may also use plain old WebDriver strategies such as by.id and by.css. Since locating by CSS selector is so common, the global variable $ is an alias for element.by.css.") If you're interested, [here](https://github.com/thenickcox/groceries) is the code.

Comment: Also, do you have your code in a fiddle or anything, so that I could take a look?

Comment: I just added a test to Protractor which shows an example of using Alerts. Check out https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/196c83a9d728e40fecd7a9f206bb985533550fde

Comment: @nickcoxdotme: Thanks for the heads up on `$`! I didn't know that was the case. [Here's the prototype code](http://plnkr.co/edit/nC1xvW81Icmza6zorJoY?p=preview) I used in conjunction with the test in my answer. How are you initializing your app? `<html ng-app>` or an alternative way? Is it in any way possible your app hasn't finished initializing at the point your test runs?

Comment: @Colin Your answer gave me an idea. In my app, I'm using a service called GoAngular (like firebase) as a back-end. It returns a promise, and it's possible that the test was trying to run the code before the promise returned. (But then I don't get why it was able to read the button text in the first test.) In any case, when I removed all that code, your test worked as written. Could you kindly submit it as an answer, and I'll mark it right?

Comment: @nickcoxdotme: Wow - I'm glad you got it sorted! I've edited my original answer to include that piece of information.

Comment: I had to use `by.buttonText('My text')` in the selector, since the test failed because it couldn't find the button by ID. Afterward the test was able to run.

Answer (score 5):

You have to wait for the browser to open/display the alert. Example using Protractor 2.2.0:

```
   var timeoutInMilliseconds = 1000;
   browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), timeoutInMilliseconds);
   var alertDialog = browser.switchTo().alert();
   expect(alertDialog.getText()).toEqual("Hello World!");
```