# How to handle modal-dialog box in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, modal-dialog, protractor

I am trying to use `sendKeys()` on a modal-dialog box on [this](http://www.gifteng.com/?login) website. This dialog box appears after clicking **Sign In** button. I cannot seem to find any way to switch focus on the box. See the [gist](https://gist.github.com/safrrhmn/23676b3ac42452e9f66c)

I tried using `browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement();` in

```
InvalidLogInUnSuccess: {
        get: function () {
            this.loginButton.click();
            browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement();
            this.email.sendKeys("Test");
        }
    }
```

with no luck and throws *ElementNotVisibleError*

> Message:
>        ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
>     (Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.101)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
>      Stacktrace:
>        ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

Comment: Does `browser.switchTo().alert()` help? ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19884387/771848))

Comment: @alecxe thanks for the quick answer. It did not help just tried. Getting ` NoSuchAlertError: no alert open` and I, also added a 2s hardcoded delay after the click to make sure it's the loading issue. But no luck

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just checked it out, let me debug a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've experienced a similar issue while testing an internal application when a popup was being opened with an *animation effect* (I think it is a culprit here) which had me think about waiting for an element inside the popup to become visible.

[`visibilityOf` expected condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf) works for me in this case:

```
var email = element(by.css('.container.login.ng-scope #email'));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(email), 5000);

email.sendKeys('test');
```

where `EC` is something I usually define globally in the `onPrepare()`:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    ...

    global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
},
```

---

Just a side note, I think the locator could be improved here:

- `ng-scope` is not something I would rely on
- there is a `model` defined on the `email` field, how about:

  ```
  element(by.model('email'));
  ```

---

FYI, the complete spec I've executed:

```
"use strict";

describe("gifteng test", function () {
    var scope = {};

    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get("http://www.gifteng.com/?login");
        browser.waitForAngular();
    });

    describe("Logging in", function () {
        it("should send keys to email", function () {
            var email = element(by.css('.container.login.ng-scope #email'));
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(email), 5000);

            email.sendKeys('test');
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Why does webstorm complaining about [ExpectedConditions](http://prntscr.com/6mmhiu)

Comment: @Saifur expected conditions were introduced in protractor `1.7.0`. Are you using `1.7.0` or above?

Comment: @Saifur also, do you have `angular-protractor-DefinitelyTyped` and `selenium-webdriver-DefinitelyTyped` libraries enabled in settings?

Comment: No sure I am going to check the version. I pulled it though webstorm [libraries](http://prntscr.com/6mmj6b)

Comment: @Saifur you can also run `npm list protractor` to check what version you have currently installed.

Comment: Huh! I did not have `Protractor` installed. Just installed and going to try the your solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74018/discussion-between-saifur-and-alecxe).

Answer (score 0):

Protractor works with promises you should write :

```
  InvalidLogInUnSuccess: {
            get:  async() => {
                await this.loginButton.click();
                await browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement();
                await this.email.sendKeys("Test");
```

just apply Promises before protractor code. I removed function and write async. so i applied async/await.

reference: [Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/4u2ppu/how_do_i_wait_for_a_modal_dialog_using_protractor/)